# Control (or set of controls) for shopping cart item in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best windows forms control(or set of controls) which give to user ability to select items from list of goods and select count for each item, that structure like shopping cart but i need to implement it on windows forms, how can i accomplish that using windows forms control, what is the best practise for that occasions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ListBox control for the list of goods ....

Then use a small textbox with a plus and minus button next to it for the counter